# Finding both child and parent by class name in one go with WebDriver?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On a typical eBay search query where more than 50 listings are returned, such as [this](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?rt=nc&LH_Complete=1&_nkw=Columbia+Hiking+Pants&LH_Sold=1&_sacat=0&LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&_sop=3&LH_ItemCondition=1000), eBay displays in the a grid format (whether you have it set up to display as grid or a list).

I'm using class name to pull out the prices using WebDriver:

[image]

```
prices = webdriver.find_all_elements_by_class_name("bidsold")
```

**The challenge:** although all prices on the page look identical in structure, the ones that are crossed out (where *Buy It Now* is not available and it's *Best offer accepted*) are actually contained within a child span of the above span:

[image]

I could pull these out separately by repeating the `find_all_elements_by_class_name` method with class *sboffer*, but (i) I will lose track of the order, and more importantly (ii) it will roughly double the time it takes to extract the prices.

The CSS selector for both types of prices also differ, as do the XPaths.

How do we catch all prices in one go?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?rt=nc&LH_Complete=1&_nkw=Columbia+Hiking+Pants&LH_Sold=1&_sacat=0&LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&_sop=3&LH_ItemCondition=1000&_pgn=2')

prices_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.amt')
prices_on_page = []
for span in prices_list:
    unsold_item = span.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.bidsold.bold')
    sold_item = span.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.sboffer')
    if len(sold_item):
        prices_on_page.append(sold_item[0].text)
    elif len(unsold_item):
        prices_on_page.append(unsold_item[0].text)
    elif span.text:
        prices_on_page.append(span.text)

print prices_on_page
driver.quit()
```

In this case, you will have track of the order and you will only query the specific span element instead of the entire page. This should improve performance.

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks. If I get the length of `prices_on_page` though, its 45, not 51. This also happens to be the length of `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("bidsold")`. See here: http://pastebin.com/v8suRmTg

Answer (score 2):

I would go for xpath- below code worked for me. It grabbed 50 prices!

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?rt=nc&LH_Complete=1&_nkw=Columbia+Hiking+Pants&LH_Sold=1&_sacat=0&LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&_sop=3&LH_ItemCondition=1000&_pgn=2')

my_prices = []
itms = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='bin']")
for i in itms:
    prices = i.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'$')]")
    val =  ','.join(i.text for i in prices)
    my_prices.append([val])
print my_prices
driver.quit()
```

Result is

```
[[u'$64.95'], [u'$59.99'], [u'$49.95'], [u'$46.89,$69.99'], [u'$44.98'], [u'$42.95'], [u'$39.99'], [u'$39.99'], [u'$37.95'], [u'$36.68'], [u'$35.96,$44.95'], [u'$34.99'], [u'$34.99'], [u'$34.95'], [u'$30.98'], [u'$29.99'], [u'$29.99'], [u'$29.65,$32.95'], [u'$29.00'], [u'$27.96,$34.95'], [u'$27.50'], [u'$27.50'], [u'$26.99,$29.99'], [u'$26.95'], [u'$26.55,$29.50'], [u'$24.99'], [u'$24.99'], [u'$24.99'], [u'$24.99'], [u'$24.98'], [u'$24.98'], [u'$24.98'], [u'$24.98'], [u'$24.98'], [u'$22.00'], [u'$22.00'], [u'$22.00'], [u'$22.00'], [u'$18.00'], [u'$18.00'], [u'$17.95'], [u'$11.99'], [u'$9.99'], [u'$6.00']]
```